# Visual Studio not remove local files when undo pending changes

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, tfs

In Visual Studio, if I add a few files to a project but then decide to undo my pending changes, the files are not removed from the project. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In most Source Control, only changed existing files are considered **changes** & new files are considered **Addition**(+) so undo pending changes removes all changes done by you in existing files.

Newly added files shown as addition you can safely **delete** as they are still not tracked in git history until committed.
**The behaviour is as expected not an issue.**

Comment: I know the file will be available if we open it on windows file explorer. But I am saying is, it should not be visible in the solution explorer of visual studio